# 'HTTPSConnection' object has no attribute 'provider'

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

So I am trying to create a new key as a string file in a particular s3 bucket, but am getting this peculiar error. I need to be able to use the k.set_contents_from_string approach, as later on I intend to download images directly to s3 bucket(without doing so locally) from a specified url.
P.S: the credentials to connect to the s3 are stored in a .aws credentials file so the authentication is happening properly.

code:

```
import boto3
from boto.s3.key import Key
import urllib3
import boto

#s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
#mybucket = s3.Bucket("bucket_name")
#mybucket
c = boto.connect_s3()
b = c.get_bucket("bucket_name")
k = Key(c)
k.key = 'foobar'
k.set_contents_from_string('This is a test of S3')
```

error:

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-29-3bd192af4319> in <module>()
          1 k = Key(c)
          2 k.key = 'foobar'
    ----> 3 k.set_contents_from_string('This is a test of S3')

    /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py in set_contents_from_string(self, string_data, headers, replace, cb, num_cb, policy, md5, reduced_redundancy, encrypt_key)
       1436         r = self.set_contents_from_file(fp, headers, replace, cb, num_cb,
       1437                                         policy, md5, reduced_redundancy,
    -> 1438                                         encrypt_key=encrypt_key)
       1439         fp.close()
       1440         return r

    /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py in set_contents_from_file(self, fp, headers, replace, cb, num_cb, policy, md5, reduced_redundancy, query_args, encrypt_key, size, rewind)
       1208         :return: The number of bytes written to the key.
       1209         """
    -> 1210         provider = self.bucket.connection.provider
       1211         headers = headers or {}
       1212         if policy:

    AttributeError: 'HTTPSConnection' object has no attribute 'provider'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line `k = Key(c)` should read `k = Key(b)` as Key expects a bucket as it's constructor parameter